# Custom SQL Metrics in apache superset to do a groupby

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-superset

I have a tables 'XYZ' as below

```
Dist        SM     Code    Target
0000022520  ISR03   SR06    48
0000022520  ISR03   SR06    48
0000022520  ISR03   SR06    48
0000022520  ISR03   SR06    48
0000022520  ISR03   SR06    48
0000022521  ISR03   SR07    16
```

I am trying to create a custom metric in superset which selects distinct values of Target when grouped by Dist,SM, Code and returns the SUM. In above example it will be 64 (48+16)

Tried the below custom sql query

```
SUM(Target_total) AS total_target
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(DISTINCT Target) AS Target_total
    FROM XYZ  GROUP BY "Dist", "SM", "Code"
) AS subquery;
```

But superset throws an error as *Error: Custom SQL fields cannot contain sub-queries.*

Is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you omitted `SELECT` before `SUM`?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm In superset the SELECT is automatically taken for query formation

Comment: Well, this is obviously a limitation of apache superset as your query [works just fine](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qPtT3QRsLRMmJyDYH94sVA/0).

Comment: Right, just trying to find out if there is any  work around

Comment: There may be a [feature flag](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/25072) work-around.